# SQL preventing null being passed into a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null

I am attempting to write a procedure but want to prevent the user from passing null to 4 variables.

It has a variable which the user can choose between two.

Eg. Chocolate or vanilla or both. So one value can remain null if required.

and the other two are mandatory. So null cannot be passed.

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lets assume you are right on that - you don;t want a parameter in your stored procedure to allow null value. and let's assume that sombody send a null by mistake.

### what would happen?

if you wish to raise an error you can do it like this

```
if (@MyParam is null) raiserror('Null values not allowed for MyParam', 16, 1)
```

if you wish the parameter to get a default value you can specify this line:

```
if (@MyParam is null) set @MyParam = 'something'
```

**in short:** there is no such an option because sql server can't ensure that null values won't arrive to the stored

Answer (score 0):

Allow `NULL` on the variables in the stored procedure.

Write T-SQL `IF` statements to check the validity of the values.

If they are not what is expected, `RAISERROR` and `RETURN` out of the procedure.

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier way, like creating a table you can set NOT NULL.